# Using lenses to operate on inner monad in StateT

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Pleease see the use of `liftIO` in the function `increment` below. I have a hunch that there's a better way to handle it using lenses. Any suggestions?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.State

data PersistentCounter = PersistentCounter {
    _cValue :: Int,
    _cFilename :: FilePath
  } deriving Show
makeLenses ''PersistentCounter

increment :: StateT PersistentCounter IO ()
increment = do
  t <- cValue <+= 1
  f <- use cFilename
  liftIO $ writeFile f $ show t
```

---

EDIT: I thought there might be a mechanism something like `zoom2, below.

```
increment :: StateT PersistentCounter IO ()
increment = do
  t <- cValue <+= 1
  zoom2 store 

store :: PersistentCounter -> IO ()
store counter =
  writeFile (counter^.cFilename) $ show (counter^.cValue)

-- | Invoke a function in the inner monad, and pass the state as
--   a parameter.
zoom2 :: Monad m => (s -> m ()) -> StateT s m ()
zoom2 f = get >>= (\s -> lift (f s)) >> return ()
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want, lens are for accessing parts of data and `liftIO` to perform IO inside a monad transformer, both are completely different things

Comment: What lens-like syntax did you have in mind for this?  It doesn't have to be real but I just want to get a sense of what your intuition is.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar in nature to `zoom`, but instead of working in a larger state, it would work in the inner monad. If there isn't such a beast, that's fine; I can write my own. My concern was that since I'm new to lenses, I was missing out on some lens-y goodness.

Comment: I've updated my question to show an example. I need to do this sort of thin in several places in my code, so I'll just use this `zoom2` function I wrote. (I'll try to come up with a better name for it!)

Comment: And now that I've written it, I see that it has nothing to do with lenses at all. Never mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written (almost) `zoom2` many times before---I usually call it `getsM`. A generic version looks like

```
-- from Control.Monad.State
gets  :: MonadState s m => (s ->   a) -> m a
getsM :: MonadState s m => (s -> m a) -> m a
getsM f = state  $ \s -> (,s) <$> f s
```

Or if you don't mind fixing a particular stack

```
-- from Control.Monad.Trans.State
gets  :: Monad m => (s ->   a) -> StateT s m a
getsM :: Monad m => (s -> m a) -> StateT s m a 
getsM f = StateT $ \s -> (,s) <$> f s
```